# Unable to find assembly 'App_Web_kplju3v2

Tags: c#, asp.net

on Local projects work ok, but on remote server in log I found this error:

```
06/10/2014 17:08-->Unable to find assembly 'App_Web_kplju3v2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.; Stack Trace:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
       at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.ReadValueFromStream(BinaryReader reader)
       at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.ReadValueFromStreamWithAssert()
       at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.DeserializeItem(String name, Boolean check)
       at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.DeserializeAllItems()
       at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Web.TraceContext.EndRequest()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestEndTrace()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
       at ASP.admin_panel_login_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4d5b117f\81bafff3\App_Web_q03tosgf.6.cs:line 0
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously); Source: mscorlib
    ------------------
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try clearing out your temporary IIS Files.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[FrameworkVersion]\Temporary ASP.NET Files\